# Django - Sqlite column names different from model field name

Tags: django, sqlite

I've had a model with a field named `enclosure_id`. I changed the field name to `enclosure_name` in the model and everywhere in the code, since that seemed more appropriate to the content.

Now the respective column in the db is called `enclosure_name_id` I do not understand how this name is created. And I'm not able to get rid of this. I've deleted the database (I'm still at a testing phase) and all migrations, it's always regenerated as `enclosure_name_id`. Nowhere in my entire code is there an occurence of `enclosure_name_id`.

If anyone could help me out, this would be great.

Best regards,
Gero

Comment: If `enclosure_name` is a foreign key, this is expected

Comment: Are you sure it's not a foreign key?

Comment: It is indeed a foreign key. Thanks a lot, then I’ll adapt to this!

Answer (score 0):

I think if you don't delete your previous migrations when deleting your litesql DB, they are applied to your new db as well. So Delete the migrations file inside your migrations folder and it should work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! So I deleted the migrations and pycache folders in the apps folders and the database. Still the same. It must be something that I’m missing, I just can’t figure out what it is that I’m not deleting.

Comment: can you edit your post and show your model ?

Comment: According to comments above, it’s expected for a ForeignKey. I was not aware of this. Thanks!